# How i can create a share facebook button inside to an email with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, email, attachment

I am trying to create a facebook share button inside to an email and share the attached video via C#.

First of all, I have attached into the email the video which i am trying to send.
But i can't create via C# the facebook button that i want to share the video.

You may find my source code so far :

```
public static string logopath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "logo.png");
public static string videopath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "test.mp4");

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string usermail = textBox1.Text;
            bool isUsermailNull = usermail.Equals("");
            Console.Out.WriteLine("The variable is " + isUsermailNull);
            if (isUsermailNull.Equals(false))
            {
                try
                {
                    MailAddress m = new MailAddress(usermail);
                    try
                    {
                        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                        message.From = new MailAddress("myemailaccount@gmail.com");
                        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(usermail));
                        message.Subject = "SUBJECT";
                        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        Attachment inlineLogo = new Attachment(logopath);
                        Attachment inlineLogo2 = new Attachment(videopath);
                        message.Attachments.Add(inlineLogo);
                        message.Attachments.Add(inlineLogo2);
                        string contentID = "Image";
                        string contentID2 = "Image2";

                        inlineLogo.ContentId = contentID;
                        inlineLogo2.ContentId = contentID2;

                        //To make the image display as inline and not as attachment

                        inlineLogo.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                        inlineLogo.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;

                        inlineLogo2.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                        inlineLogo2.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;

                        //To embed image in email
                        //string pass = "123456";
                        message.Body = "<html><body> <h1 align=\"center\"><img src=\"cid:" + contentID + "\"> </h1><video width=\"400\" controls><source src=\"cid:" + contentID2 + "\" type=\"video/mp4\">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video> <h1 align=\"center\">Project</h1> "
                        + " <h2 align=\"center\"> NameofProject </h2><h2 align=\"center\">You may find attached your video</h2><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7\"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script> <div class=\"fb-video\" data-href=\"cid:" + contentID2 + "\" data-width=\"500\" data-show-text=\"false\"><div class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\"><blockquote cite=\"cid:" + contentID2 + "\"><a href=\"cid:" + contentID2 + "\" >Share with your Friends</a><p>Project</p>Created by <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/mysite/?fref=ts&ref=br_tf\">MyProject</a>  </blockquote>    </div>  </div> <h3 align=\"center\"> Thank you</h3> <h2 align=\"center\">Details</h2> <h2 align=\"center\"> Mail us : myemailaccount@gmail.com</h2> </body></html>";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemailaccount@gmail.com", "password");
                        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        smtp.Timeout = 5000000;
                        smtp.Send(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("err: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                    this.Close();
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You haven't put correct email address. Try again!!!!");
                }
                //Kill all on screen keyboards
                Process[] oskProcessArray = Process.GetProcessesByName("TabTip");
                foreach (Process onscreenProcess in oskProcessArray)
                {
                    onscreenProcess.Kill();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The textbox is null. Please insert an appropriate email address");
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need add in body a hmtl `<a>` with a url that contains your file like for example:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=**MYURL**" style="color:#202020;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:normal;text-align:center;text-decoration:none" class="gmail_msg" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?**CONFIDENTIAL**">Share in Facebook</a>
```